# Can Lambda Environment vars can store a list?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

Can lambda's Environment variables store a list/array?
I have a lambda which require some email ids(stored as list) which I am trying to pass through environment vars. Can this be done or is it not allowed?

`list_email=['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@gmail.com']`

I have to get this list from terraform code so i can't directly call it in python code.  So that is why I am trying to pass it in as an env var.

Comment: No, create a comma separated list with the emails and use split in your python code.

Comment: I have to get this list from terraform code so i can't directly call it in python code..so that is why I am trying to pass it in env var. @kgiannakakis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform has a [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) function, which "encodes a given value to a string using JSON syntax".

Set the stringified version as the lambda env var, then parse it back to a list using Python.

Comment: read the value like json.loads(os.environ['list_email'])